# echo an SQL row for each using a checkbox and a submit button

Tags: php, sql, for-loop, checkbox, row

I will simplify the code in order to highlight what I need:

```
<form id="highlighttable" name=form1 method="POST">
    
    <div class="form-group">
        <button name="save_multicheckbox" class="btn-primary">Save Checkbox</button>
    </div>
    <?php
      if(isset($_POST['save_multicheckbox'])){
        echo "<p>yes</p>";
        $checklist = $_POST['ckb'];
        foreach($checklist as $list) {
            echo "<p>as</p>";
        }
      }
    ?>
        <table>
        <tr id="col-title">
                    <th>ID Number</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Post Date</th>
                    <th>Url</th>
                    <th>Feature</th>
                </tr>

                <?php foreach($result as $res){
                        ?><tr>
                            <td><h6><?php echo $res->id_num; ?></h6></td>
                            <td><h6>Lorem</h6></td>
                            <td><h6>Lorem</h6></td>
                            <td><h6>Lorem</h6></td>
                            <td><h6>Lorem</h6></td>
                            <td id="h-center"><input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" onclick="chkcontrol(<?php echo $res->chkbox_num; ?>)">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php
                    } ?>
        </table>
 </form>
```

I have foreach from my select query, which outputs table rows below:

```
<?php foreach($result as $res){} ?>
```

output:

[image: 1]

what I am trying to do is to echo or retrieve the rest of the rows on each selected row by marking what I want to get with a checkbox (last column)

```
<td id="h-center"><input type="checkbox" name="ckb" onclick="chkcontrol(<?php echo $res->chkbox_num; ?>)"></td>
```

my problem is that my foreach does not output the selected rows with that I tried below:

```
      if(isset($_POST['save_multicheckbox'])){
        echo "<p>yes</p>";
        $checklist = $_POST['ckb'];
        foreach($checklist as $list) {
            echo "<p>as</p>";
        }
      }
```

first I tried to add an echo inside the button to check if it works and it does, I am just wondering how to show the selected rows. Is there maybe an issue with the variable I am using to get it? my attempt is `$checklist = $_POST['ckb'];` where `ckb` is the name of the checkbox.

Clarification: the screenshot below shows my foreach inside my `onclick` they have a value starting from 0

[image: 2]

Comment: If you _simplify_ if that the word, things too much they stop making much sense and we get bored and move on

Comment: I think you are saying this line `<?php echo $res->chkbox_num; ?>` is not getting the value of `$res->chkbox_num;` put into the parameter? Is that right?? If so, it woudl be useful to see proof that the column `$res->chkbox_num;` is actually in the resultset

Comment: Unrelated fyi: `id` attributes _must_ be unique. You have loop that generates multiple `id="h-center"` - which is invalid

Comment: updated and clarified

Comment: Well it shows one of the lines generated by the foreach. I ___assume again___ all the lines show a parameter value of `1`. Is that so?

Comment: each row increments like: chkcontrol(0) chkcontrol(1) chkcontrol(2) chkcontrol(3)

Comment: Hi, do you want to show selected checkboxes row only after click of your `save_multicheckbox` button ?

Answer (score 0):

You should your foreach loop to only display the rows that have been selected by checking if their corresponding checkbox has been checked.
You can do this by adding an if statement inside your loop like this:

```
foreach($result as $res) {
  if(isset($_POST['ckb'][$res->id])) {
    // display the row here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several options.
First you need to chnage rendering part of table with checkbox id.
You have to use $res->id because you will save data whatever you change on checkbox.

```
<td id="h-center"><input type="hidden" name="ckb_data[<?php echo $res->chkbox_num; ?>]"><input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" onclick="chkcontrol(<?php echo $res->chkbox_num; ?>)"></td>
```

If you wanna get rest of columns by making selection, then you need to handle this part at js function named chkcontrol().Because if you wanna get something of rest columns, you have to use js code and then send request.

```
function chkcontrol(id){
   var data = '';
   $(this).parent().prevAll().each(function(){
       // get data of columns
   });
}
```

Now you can output data from post request.

```
if(isset($_POST['save_multicheckbox'])){
    echo "<p>yes</p>";
    $checklist = $_POST['ckb'];
    $checklist_data = $_POST['ckb_data']
    foreach($reuslt as $row) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_POST['ckb_data'][$row->chkbox_num]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: what should be the syntax of retrieving the columns? (in the get data of columns)

Comment: If you wanna get data in chkcontrol function, try like this.

`var data = []
 $(this).parent().prevAll().each(function(){
       // let's assume that the columns have only text.
       data.push($(this).text());
 });`
$('input[name="ckb_data['+id+']"]').val(JSON.stringify(data));`
 in backend part 
`$data = json_decode($_POST['ckb_data'][$row->chkbox_num], true);`
 
Let me know if you have any question

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

Your `<button>` tag has no `type=` attribute. It is extremely important that you mention the `type=` for every button you are adding in your application. This is the proper and safe way to submit the form.
You can use three basic types as below :

1. For no action after you click, you can use `type="button"`.
2. To reset/clear the form without reloading, use `type="reset"`.
3. To submit the form, use `type="submit"`.

```
<button type="submit" name="save_multicheckbox" class="btn-primary">Save Checkbox</button>
```

Since your button is submitting the form, we dont want any javascript to do this task. By saying this, lets modify your `<input>` tag as below

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="<?=$res->chkbox_num?>"></td>
```

Now lets assume we are submitting the form with some selected checkboxes and we need to capture the values of these checkboxes which are checked by the user.

```
<?php 
      if(isset($_POST['save_multicheckbox']))
      {
         // checking all submitted values.
         echo json_encode($_POST['ckb']);
      }
?>
```

Comment: `type` is not needed for buttons. `type="submit"` is the default for buttons in a form

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the selected checkbox values on submit, You have to specify the `value` attribute to the checkbox. Please change your checkbox input as below

```
<input type="checkbox" name="ckb[]" value="<?php echo $res->chkbox_num; ?>">
```

Here I have removed `chkcontrol` but you can add it if you have this function definition in js.

Then you can check selected checkbox values by following code

```
if(isset($_POST['save_multicheckbox'])){
        // echo "<p>yes</p>";
        $checklist = $_POST['ckb'];
        foreach($checklist as $list) {
            echo "<p>".$list."</p>";
        }
```